# What does status code -1 in firebug mean?

Tags: firebug, http-status-codes

Can anyone tell what does status code -1 stands for in firebug ? I searched the net but could not find it.

[image: Here is a snapshot for more clarity]

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this status code?

Comment: I have some jpg files on my website which shows -1 status code

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot to your question? It's hard to understand what you mean with "status code -1".